# SQL find matches between two tables using like

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have two tables:

`table 1` - ~230 000 rows and containing product serial numbers
`table 2` - ~4700 row and also containing product serial numbers but in a bit different format

`table 1` serial numbers look something like 123456
`table 2` serial numbers look something like ABC123456DGF

I need to find out how many serial numbers from table 2 are actually present in table 1. I could do it using LIKE function but I have a hard time figuring out how to properly loop it through the whole table so every row gets tested against table 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: assuming that `ABC` and `DGF` are dynamic values, then how do you do expect to do it without using `LIKE`

Comment: You cannot do it with using like as '%12345%' can also return you 'ABC12345678EFG'

Comment: Is the numerical part in each case of known fixed length?

Comment: Which database do you use? From your example consists serial numbers only of digits and pre and suffix only of letters?

Comment: Safest way would be if there is a method to convert all serial numbers in table 2 to the format of table 1 - then you do not need the `LIKE` to compare them. To do this, there are ways to return only the number part of the serial number from table 2.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you..

```
declare @var varchar(50)='ABC123456DGF'

SELECT LEFT(Val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Val+'a')-1) from(

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@var, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @var), LEN(@var)) Val
) x

select * from Table_1 where product_serial_numbers = @var
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would probably adapt the serial numbers in table2...

```
SELECT Substr(serial_no,4,10) FROM Table 2
```

And then join it to table1

```
SELECT T1.serial_no
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Substr(serial_no,4,10) as serial_no FROM Table2) T2
ON T1.serial_no T2.serial_no
```